# Can I use Sphinx to programmatically access parsed documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring, docutils

I can use `docutils` to parse reStructuredText formatted docstrings, but it doesn't parse the directives themselves that belong to the Python domain. For example, `:type path: unicode` gets parsed as:

```
<field>
        <field_name>type path</field_name>
        <field_body>
                <paragraph>unicode</paragraph>
        </field_body>
</field>
```

Can I use Sphinx to programmatically get more meaning out of it? I.e. parameter names, etc?

Comment: I think this should be possible by [writing a Sphinx extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/tutorial.html) that does whatever you want by inspecting the generated doctree. Also checking the list of [available builders](http://sphinx-doc.org/builders.html) and looking at their source could help.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first idea too, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8125238/407651